# Need to add content in the 'value' field

Tags: imacros

This is a dropdown box that users has to enter value and the system autocompletes the results.

I used this tag but the value is added for just a second and dissapeared.
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:FormName_input ATTR=NAME:FormName_input content=test

So I need to add test content in the field value="".

The html is like this

input name="FormName_input" class="ui-autocomplete-input ui-inputfield ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-left" id="FormName_input" role="textbox" aria-disabled="false" aria-readonly="false" aria-labelledby="j_idt86" aria-autocomplete="listbox" type="text" placeholder="Select" value="" autocomplete="off">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try these [`EVENT`](http://wiki.imacros.net/EVENT) commands:

```
EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="#FormName_input" BUTTON=0
EVENTS TYPE=KEYPRESS SELECTOR="#FormName_input" CHARS="test"
```